# jQuery join two radio

Tags: jquery

How I can connect radios with different names? I have something like that

```
- Cash (name=payment)
- Card (name=payment)
-- Visa (name=paymentCard)
-- MasterCard (name=paymentCard)
```

And when I will click 'Visa' then I want also have checked 'Card' by jQuery, and ofcourse when I will click after that 'Cash' it will remove checked from radios with name=paymentCard.

html code:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="INPUT-payment" value="Cash" checked="checked">Cash</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="INPUT-payment" value="Card" class="card">Card</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="INPUT-paymentCard" value="Visa">Visa</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="INPUT-paymentCard" value="MasterCard">MasterCard</label>
```

jquery code:

```
$('input[name=INPUT-paymentCard]').on('click', function(){
    $('input[value=Card').attr('checked', true);
});

$('input[name=INPUT-payment]').on('click', function(){
    $('input[name=INPUT-paymentCard]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

With this code when I will choose Visa it is checking Card, but when I will check Cash and then again Visa it is not checking Card anymore.

link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cRQB2/

Comment: can you update your question with jquery code and html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<input name="payment" type="radio" class="payment cash"/> Cash 
<input name="payment" type="radio" class="payment card"/> Card

<input name="paymentCard" type="radio" class="paymentCard visa"/> Visa 
<input name="paymentCard" type="radio" class="paymentCard Master"/> MasterCard
```

and

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $payments = $('input.payment').change(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('card')){
            $cards.prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
    var $cards = $('input.paymentCard').change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $payments.filter('.card').prop('checked', true);
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g34DN/)